# How send Image in one class to another class to attach mail body using java

Tags: java, email

In my java web application, I need to add image to body mail content and i pass the text body to mail one class to another class but i need to send images dynamically how can i send image my images folder is `WebContent/Images/ABC.JPG` but how can i attach with mail body

my class i generated message data form database here send to another class

WishesDAO.java: this class have 3 type of methods based on this methods i need to send individual images to mail class

```
public  String method()
{
   rs =  stmnt.executeQuery(DOBQuery);
            while(rs.next())//DOB
             {              

                String From="ABC@hai.com";
                String To=rs.getString("Emailid");              
                String Name=rs.getString("Ename");                          
               String htmlText = "<img src=Images/ABC.JPG/>";
                String text="Hi "+Name.toString()+","+"\n\n"+"Happy BirthDay....!"+"\n\n"+htmlText+"\n\nFrom,\nTeam";
                SendEmail stp=new SendEmail();
                stp.mail(From, To,Name,text);
             }
}
```

SendEmail.java:

```
 try {
             // Create a default MimeMessage object.
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

             // Set From: header field of the header.
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(From));

             // Set To: header field of the header.
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(To));

             // Set Subject: header field
             message.setSubject("Wishes!", "UTF-8");

             // Now set the actual message

             message.setContent(text, "text/html");// getting the text from WishesDAO.java
             // Send message
             Transport.send(message);           
             msg=message.toString();
          }catch (MessagingException mex) {
             mex.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println(mex);
          }
```

how can i send images anyone please tell

Exception 1:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
>   nested exception is:  java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   \WebContent\Images\HappyBirthday.JPG (The system cannot find the path
>   specified) javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending
>   message;   nested exception is:   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   \WebContent\Images\HappyBirthday.JPG (The system cannot find the path
>   specified)    at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1167)
>     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)   at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   Model.SendEmail.mail(SendEmail.java:58)   at
>   Model.WishesDAO.method(WishesDAO.java:73)     at
>   Model.Testing.run(Testing.java:24)    at
>   java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: \WebContent\Images\HappyBirthday.JPG
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1574)  at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:948)   at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:538)     at
>   com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:103)
>     at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1574)  at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1840)    at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1119)
>     ... 7 more

my image:

[image path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCmy6.png)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.
To use image in email you need to use `BodyPart` and `DataSource` something like this,

First Add HTML

```
// first part (the html)
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";
messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
// add it
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Then add the image by creating a Datahandler as follows:

```
// second part (the image)
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(
 "/home/manisha/javamail-mini-logo.png");

messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
message.setContent(multipart);
```

you can refer to [Tutorials point example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_inlineimage_in_email.htm) or go threw any other tutorial, just google it you will get plenty.

I hope this helps.

Comment: HI,@Darshan Thakkar, I tried with your code i got errors. I am sending mail to two people i am getting errors can u please see my update question. could you please tell me where i did mistake

Comment: Hi @phani as per your errors, com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException is for connection error usual cause for this is wrong email server or host, if you are working in big organization they may have firewall blocking this service too, so you have to debug and find source of error by yourself only, but as per my guess reasons should be mentioned above. second error is quite self explained java.io.FileNotFoundException is file not found exception. my advice is make separate application which sends small simple mail, then try to add image and if all workout add code in actual project.

Comment: How can i take `webcontent/images/img.jpg` folder path i taken like this `D:/Desktop/Tool/Wishes/WebContent/Images/img.jpg` mail sent with image  not directly displays attached like a file when i click it open next page  but text is not displaying before image this path is not suitable for when host into live and all time how can i take `webcontent path`

Comment: 1. How to get image? Ans: Make resource folder in your project and get image from there using relative path. 2. Image as attachment. Ans : Did you go threw link I provided in answer? that is perfect example of how to get image "in email" and not as attachment.

Comment: Hi,@Darshan Thakkar, I take the path like this `String imgpath="/resources/img.JPG";`  but it shows exception while sending mail where i did mistake could you please tell me